# fs.stat never finds file

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to create a function in node that will generate an article page if it can find the requested article's json, but I can't even get fs.stat to tell me that a file exists. I've verified the directory and the filename of the script with the __dirname and __filename globals, but I can't even get my function to find a file that's in the same directory as the script, much less a different directory.

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var router = express.Router();

var articlePage = function home(req, res) {
    console.log(__dirname + __filename);
    fs.stat('foo.txt', function(err, stat) {
        if(err == null) {
            console.log('File exists');
            res.send("filefound"); //this never is triggered
        } else if(err.code == 'ENOENT') {
            console.log("file does not exist");
            res.status(404).send('file not found');
        } else {
            console.log('Some error has occured');
        }
        });
};
router.get('/article/:articleName', articlePage);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Relative paths (including just a filename) passed to `fs.stat()` are relative to the _current working directory_, not to `__dirname`.

Comment: how would i know what the current working directory is, is that the directory that app.js runs out of?

Comment: If you don't change it in the code (with [`process.chdir()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_chdir_directory)), it's the directory where you started the Node process that runs your app. You can retrieve it using [`process.cwd()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd).

Comment: Don't rely on the current working directory.  Instead, built a full path name starting with `__dirname` since you should know where the desired file is relative to that.